# quicksort and mergesort bad memory alloc (not sorting over 32k elements)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, memory-management

FIXED - I included .cpp files too, cause of linker problems with template class - I had a memory leak in mergesort.cpp, which caused quicksort (included after) to not work too. Introsort was included before, so worked fine.

my qsort algorithm:

```
#include "quicksort.h"

template <class typ> 
void quicksort(typ* tab, long int begin, long int end) {
  long int i = begin; 
  long int j = end;
  typ tmp;
  typ pivot = tab[(begin + end) / 2];

  /* podziel */
  while (i <= j) {
        while (tab[i] < pivot)
              i++;
        while (tab[j] > pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = tab[i];
              tab[i] = tab[j];
              tab[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  };

  /* rekurencja */
  if (begin < j)
        quicksort(tab, begin, j);
  if (i < end)
        quicksort(tab, i, end); 
}
```

I've build this in 2 different computers with Visual Studio 11 (win 64) and with dev c++. Same happens to my mergesort. 32002 elements and no more.

mergesort:

```
#include "mergesort.h"

using namespace std;


template <class typ>
void merge(typ *tab, long int begin, long int mid, long int end){
 typ *tab_pom = new typ[end+1];
 long int  i,j,k;

 i=begin; //pierwsza czesc
 j=mid+1; //druga czesc
 k=0;

 while ( (i<=mid) && (j<=end) ){ //pierwsze mniej niz srodek drugie mniej niz koniec
           if(tab[i] < tab[j]){
                tab_pom[k]=tab[i];
                i++;
                k++;
           }else{
                tab_pom[k]=tab[j];                
                j++;
                k++;
           }   
 }

 if (!(i<=mid)){
      while(j<=end){  
           tab_pom[k]=tab[j];
           k++;
           j++;
      } 
 }else{

      if (!(j<=end)){
           while(i<=mid){
                tab_pom[k]=tab[i];
                k++;
                i++;
           } 
      }
 }
 k=0;
 for (i=begin;i<=end;i++){
      tab[i]=tab_pom[k];
      k++;
 }         
}


// dzieli dane az do otzrymania posortowanych tablic jedno elementowych

template <class typ>
void merge_sort(typ *tab, long int begin, long int end){
 long int mid;

 if (begin < end){
      mid=(begin+end)/2;
      merge_sort(tab,begin,mid);
      merge_sort(tab,mid+1,end);
      merge(tab,begin,mid,end);
 }    
}
```

I've wrote also introsort, which works perfect for any amount of elements. I tried increasing stack size in Visual Studio 11 -> project -> properties -> linker -> stack reserve size -> 80000000. Nothing changes. Any help appreciated.

source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "introspectiv.h"
#include "introspectiv.cpp"
#include "mergesort.h"
#include "mergesort.cpp"
#include "quicksort.h"
#include "quicksort.cpp"

using namespace std;

//funkcja do kopiowania tablicy 
template<class typ>
void kopiuj(typ* tabl_1, typ* tabl_2, int indeks){
for (int i = 0 ; i < indeks ; i++) tabl_2[i] = tabl_1[i];
}

int main() {
//tworzy tablice
cout << "podaj rozmiary tablicy wypelnionej losowymi liczbami: ";
int wybor;
clock_t czas[7];
clock_t start, stop;
long int n, i, end, begin;
cin >> n;
int *tablica = new int[n];
int *tab_pom = new int[n];
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    tablica[i] = rand() % 100;
}

end = n-1;
begin = 0;

float procent[] = {0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99, 0.997};

cout << endl << "wybierz algorytm sortowania: " << endl;
cout << "quicksort - 1 " << endl;
cout << "mergesort - 2 " << endl;
cout << "introspektywne - 3 " << endl;
cin >> wybor;
switch (wybor)
{
case 1: {
    for (i=0; i<7; i++){
        kopiuj(tablica, tab_pom, end);
        end = end*procent[i]; 
        quicksort(tab_pom, begin , end);

        end = n-1;
        start=clock();
        quicksort(tab_pom, begin , end);
        stop=clock();  
        czas[i] = stop-start;

            }
        }

case 2: {
    start=clock();  
    merge_sort(tablica, begin , end);
    stop=clock();
        }
case 3: {
    start=clock();
    introspective(tablica, n);
    stop=clock();
        }
default: break;
    }


//for (i=0; i<n; i++){
//  cout<<tablica[i]<< " ";
//}

cout << endl << "Czas wybranego sortowania: " << endl; 

for (i=0; i<7; i++){
cout << "Dla " << procent[i]*100 << "% posortowanych danych: " << czas[i] << " ms"    << endl << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

its not finished for counting times in intro and mergesort.

Comment: What is the concrete `typ` you are sorting?

Comment: How do you call the functions? How do you allocate the collection to sort?

Comment: I'm guessing something gets implicitly converted to short, but no idea what. Maybe log your indexes (begin, end *and* the result of (begin+end)/2) on each recursion and see what happens?

Comment: Can there be some multiplication in the < operator for typ? Could you please provide description on the type you are using to test?

Comment: While a little OT, it looks like you have a memory leak in your `merge` function where you are allocating an block of memory using `new`, but never call `delete` to free it.

Comment: That looks like the quicksort from [algolist.net](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort) and it works on my machine. What is `typ` and how is `operator<` defined for it?

Comment: In your update you initialize `tablica` but you are passing `tab_pom` to quicksort.

Comment: im using int for testing, and operator is not overloaded.

Comment: sorry for confusion, i had to copy tablica to tab_pom, but thats not the case, i tested it for tablica before and same problem - almost no time to sort 32000 elements, after that program stops working.

Comment: I just tested your quicksort on VS2010 Release and Debug builds with 32000 and 3200000 elements. It orders the array correctly and runs cleanly. Your quicksort problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: If you want to be safe, you shouldn't locate the midpoint using `(begin + end) / 2`, as it may overflow. Use `begin + (end - begin) / 2` instead.

Comment: @Jason that wasn't OT at all.

Comment: @WillNess : I didn't realize he was making so many allocations that he would run into an exception because of memory fragmentation (I'm assuming) ... I mean if you had 2GB+ on a machine, and your object wasn't too big, I would think you could make lots of calls to `new` without a `bad_alloc` being thrown.  Nice to know that fixed the issue :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick sort**: With 32000 elements, quick sort only goes about 15 deep in recursion, you shouldn't worry about the stack size. Problem might be though that the object you try to pass is a local variable in a function, thus has a limited size. Try allocating it as a global or a static variable, eg:

```
void myfunction(){
    static int myelements[40000];
    //...
    merge_sort(myelements, 0, sizeof(myelements)/sizeof(int));
    //....
}
```

**Merge sort**: I see you call new a tons of times, but no delete. I don't see why you need to allocate memory anyways, you could just use pointers instead. Try adding

```
delete[] tab_pom;
```

At the end of merge;

Next  time try to give a little more diagnostics help, than it doesn't work. Error message perhaps.
Cheers, hope it was helpful.

Comment: i have to allocate it dynamically, number of elements is user input.

Comment: Well, I dont know how this happened, but adding delete[] tab_pom;
At the end of merge fixed both mergergesort AND QUICKSORT. Magic happens. Thanks ;)

Comment: I know how - no magic. Lots of allocations in mergesort caused `bad_alloc`. And lack of `break` in `switch` caused mergesort to be run also for quicksort.